# Transformer total power

Tags: power, transformer

In my power electronics textbook it is said that total transformer power is *S<sub>total</sub> = (S1 + S2)/2* (VA) where *S1* is transformer primary side power and *S2* is transformer secondary side power.

I am the first time seeing this equation and can't find proof (in textbook or internet) of why this is true. Why is this true?

Example from the textbook:

[image]

Given: *Id = 22A, R = 5 Ohm, U1 = 220V*

1. *Ud = Id * R = 110 V*
2. *U2 = Ud / 0.9 = 122.2V * (Effective voltage)
3. *I2 = Id = 22A*
4. *kTR = U1 / U2 = 220 / 122.2 = 1.8* (transformer turn ration)
5. *I1 = Id / kTR = 22 / 1.8 = 12.2A*
6. *S1 = I1 * U1 = 12.2 * 220 = 2648 VA*
7. *S2 = I2 * U2 = 22 * 122.2 = 2688 VA*
8. *Str = (S1 + S2) / 2 = (2648 + 2688) / 2 = 2668 VA*

Comment: You won't find proof on the internet since this is the average of input and output.  Normally, transformers are rated based on output, S2.  But S1 will be slightly larger than S2 due to losses.  S1 is what the source puts in.  And the average is a tad misleading, since it will be between S2 and S1..

Comment: Strange. Which textbook?

Comment: @winny It is a university textbook written only in the Latvian language. You won't find this textbook on the internet or in English.

Comment: Hi! As I said in the answer... this formula is used only for transformer constructive power comparison. For example, to compute the approximate size of an autotransformer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this formula is used to determine the equivalent constructive power of a transformer. Explaining: a 2000kVA 13800/380V transformer has two windings (primary and secondary) each one being 2000kVA, resulting in 2000kVA of constructive power.

Things get more complicated when we talk about special transformers, such as when there are several simultaneous voltages at low voltage, for example, 2000kVA 13800/400|220V. This LV winding will have two outputs and part of the current from the higher voltage output will flow in the lower voltage winding. The constructive power of this transformer will be greater than 2000kVA.

Another very useful case is to check the equivalent size of an autotransformer. This formula can be applied to common and series windings to calculate their constructive power, which will be less than the rated power (that will be smaller the closer the voltage ratio is to 1).